# ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap in console offers no default values

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

i tried to install ng-bootstrap for creating a most simple helloWorld angular-bootstrap app.

i found i have to use ( https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#installation ):

ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

if others using it it looks like so:

[image: this working look diffeent]

but when i using it looks like so:

`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

then it looks like so:

[image]

I tried to get forward by pressing enter. expected its using default - values.
But it offers no default - values.

What could i do?

I want to create a helloWorld angular-bootstrap app and it seems something wrong with my system i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found if this `ng-latin console` is useful for that, but found another way:

1. https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#installation
2. https://angular.io/cli

this works for me:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-first-project
cd my-first-project/
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```